# Integrate CMS Pages and Others to the Main Menu

Tags: catalog, cms, navigation, magento-community

I think this is a quite common problem: There are normal products categories but also some additional CMS pages which could be included in the main shop navigation.

In some shops I have seen the solution, that content was put in a CMS block and the category switched to "display only CMS" block to resemble a navigation for the shop content.

But I do not think that this is a best practice.

Are there better workarounds in Community Edition? (I know there is a Enterprise Edition feature to do this).

Or is there a well-known open source module helping with that?

Comment: If you ask me, this is best practice. :-)

Comment: Doh! @FabianBlechschmidt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with Magento CE 1.7 there is this event available `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before` that allows you to add any items to the top menu.
For example it is used to add the categories to top menu in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer::addCatalogToTopmenuItems()`.
The only constraint is that your top menu block should look like this in `page.xml`

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
    <label>Navigation Bar</label>
    <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
</block>
```

If your theme is somehow similar with the default theme for 1.7 you should be able to add links to the top menu using this event.
Note: in 1.7 the top menu is rendered by this template: `page/html/topmenu.phtml`.

Comment: remark: seems to be only available starting from 1.7

Answer (score 4):

There's definitely no built-in possibility to do this. Also I don't see any quick and pretty way to achieve this without writing a module.

The problem is to determine which of CMS pages have to be included into menu.

In addition to the solution you just described I can also suggest creating a static block consisting of `<li>` nodes and then injecting it into `catalog/navigation/top.phtml` template of your theme. This will give admin an opportunity to control what pages will be included into menu. No quite nice approach also if you ask me.

Another approach may be to add one or two (before and after categories) child blocks to `catalog.topnav` and also pulling them in `catalog/navigation/top.phtml` template. Then the CMS page can be added to menu with Custom Layout Update. Not nice approach either.

I would also like to know if there's an existing extension which automates it.

Comment: I think it would be nice to add these blocks and change the template, so the base template is untouched

Comment: The second approach, with some before and after block sounds quite nice.

Answer (score 1):

One of the way is to create normal category and rewrite it to related CMS page using `Catalog` > `URL Rewrite Management` section.
For more:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar

Comment: This is actually a quite amazing solution - it lacks a little bit of comfort, so it would be cool to have a module which sets up this kind of config automatically. Also what I do not like is that the link in `<a href>` tag is still the category name and then there is a redirect to the CMS page (for example)

Comment: Also, it may break some styling, because it wont add class to the category in the nav because it is not the same as the CMS page.

Answer (score 0):

An extension that we've used before is [JR_CleverCMS](https://github.com/jreinke/magento-clever-cms). Unfortunately it's no longer available on GitHub, but it is avalable [here](https://www.bubbleshop.net/magento-cms-tree.html), as CMS Tree.

It gives the ability to structure CMS pages in a hierarchical tree, and to display pages in the navigation menu.

---

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension which enable you to manage your full navigation including cms pages and other links directly from Magento categories. http://www.typoart.dk/en/magento-moduler/typoart-menu-cms-module.html

Disclaimer: I am working at the company selling this extension.